# Magento2 customer account navigation wishlist Items how to display in phtml

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

In `app\code\Magento\Wishlist\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`file,I find the block

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Link" name="wish-list-link" after="my-account-link"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

And in `app\code\Magento\Wishlist\Block\Link.php`Specifies the template file

```
protected $_template = 'Magento_Wishlist::link.phtml';
```

So I open `app\code\Magento\Wishlist\view\frontend\templates\link.phtml`

```
<li class="link wishlist" data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'">
    <a <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?>
        <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter -->
        <span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </a>
</li>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "wishlist": {
                        "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It looks like using knockoutjs.
This page  `app\code\Magento\Wishlist\view\frontend\web\js\view\wishlist.js`
and file `app\code\Magento\Customer\view\frontend\web\js\customer-data.js`

But I still do not understand,JavaScript is how to get the number wishlist.

```
data-bind="text: wishlist().counter"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside wishlist module, **link.phtml** file,

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "wishlist": {
                        "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

This file is called: **magento2/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/web/js/view/wishlist.js**

Inside this file you can check,

> this.wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist');

Here wishlist is passed into **magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js**

In customer-data.js file you can check get() method call,

Here sectionName is passed as wishlist,

```
get: function (sectionName) {
            return buffer.get(sectionName);
},
```

above file called your modules `CustomerData/Wishlist.php` file,

Now you can check in **magento2/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php file**,

```
public function getSectionData()
    {
        $counter = $this->getCounter();
        return [
            'counter' => $counter,
            'items' => $counter ? $this->getItems() : [],
        ];
    }

So you can access counter as wishlist().counter and wishlist items as wishlist().items using knockout js.
```

for wishlist().items access in,

`/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/sidebar.phtml`

you can check call,

```
 <ol class="product-items no-display" id="wishlist-sidebar" data-bind="foreach: wishlist().items, css: {'no-display': null}"></ol>
```

Here is same concept.

Comment: Thank you very much for any help you explain in great detail！！！

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya this returns only the last 3 items how get all items?

Answer (score 0):

Check following file:

**Magento/Wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php**

```
public function getSectionData()
    {
        $counter = $this->getCounter();
        return [
            'counter' => $counter,
            'items' => $counter ? $this->getItems() : [],
        ];
    }
```

`wishlist().counter` return php counter.