# Magento 2 - dataPost.js override - get error

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I creating module for guest wishlist on Magento 2.
There is mage library contains many js files. 
One of them is **dataPost.js** in directory **mage**.
I need overwrite function **postData** in it.
This is jQuery Widget.

What I have:

> requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  map: {
   '*': {
     'mage/dataPost': '<VENDOR_MODULE>/js/wishlist-data-post'
    }
 }
};
```

> VENDOR_MODULE/js/wishlist-data-post.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/ui',
  'mage/template',
], function($) {
  'use strict';

  $.widget('custom.dataPost', $.mage.dataPost, {
    postData: function(params) {
      e.preventDefault();
      debugger;
      return this._super();
    }
  });

  return $.custom.dataPost;
});
```

I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: base is not a constructor

I cannot do it like there because it isn't Magento_UI: [Magento2 customer account navigation wishlist Items how to display in phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125490/magento2-customer-account-navigation-wishlist-items-how-to-display-in-phtml)

No right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713696/not-able-to-override-collapsible-js-in-magento-2

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you find any way to override dataPost.js?

Comment: Check my answear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 options available. I use first, because was simpler and work fine. What was wrong - I used `map` not `mixins` so `this._super();` don't any parent - we override file than we extend.

Solution - first option

Copy `lib/web/mage/dataPost.js` to the theme as `THEME/web/js/mage/dataPost.js`
Edit `THEME/requirejs-config.js` with this:

```
var config = {
  map: {
   '*': {
     'mage/dataPost': 'js/mage/dataPost'
    }
 }
};
```

Now body of this file is editable in theme and used in system as default.

**IMPORTANT: Remove symlink from `pub\static`, otherwise you stuck with old file ;( This is why we have many problem because symlinks don't automatically update after are created.**

Better options is to use `mixins` in `THEME/requirejs-config.js` but for me, and this file, not work correct.

Comment: i apply this but getting in console error

Comment: What error? It will help others having issues with this.